# SqlAlchemy SQLServer and the date() function

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm

I have this code in sqlAlchemy:

```
result = session.query(FXHoliday).where(
           and_(
              FXHoliday.country_region_code == country, 
              func.DATE(FXHoliday.event_date) == when.date()
           )
         ).all()
```

Now this functions works like charm but in sqlserver :( ...

The above function is translate in

```
 SELECT [FX_HOLIDAY].countryorregion AS [FX_HOLIDAY_countryorregion],      
        [FX_HOLIDAY].holidayname AS [FX_HOLIDAY_holidayname], 
        [FX_HOLIDAY].normalizeholidayname AS [FX_HOLIDAY_normalizeholidayname], 
        [FX_HOLIDAY].ispaidtimeoff AS [FX_HOLIDAY_ispaidtimeoff], 
        [FX_HOLIDAY].countryregioncode AS [FX_HOLIDAY_countryregioncode],       
        [FX_HOLIDAY].date AS [FX_HOLIDAY_date]

 FROM [FX_HOLIDAY]

 WHERE [FX_HOLIDAY].countryregioncode = ? 
       AND 
       DATE([FX_HOLIDAY].date) = ?
```

And it is correct, however there is no DATE() in sqlserver.
I can fix the problem making the date column varchar, so that I can use:

```
  FXHoliday.event_date == when.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

But it's REALLY an UGLY solution.
I was wondering if some developer found a better and more elegant solution ....

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to make sure that a `datetime` object (what I'm assuming `when` is) is interpreted as a `date`.

There's an sqlalchemy function for this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

result = session.query(FXHoliday).where(
           and_(
              FXHoliday.country_region_code == country, 
              FXHoliday.event_date == func.date(when)
           )
         ).all()
```

Though you're using func.DATE for the first part, just use it for both.

UPDATE: I think you're trying to cast a pre-existing DATE column as a DATE, but what you really want to cast is the pythonic object.

Comment: The date() function provided by sqlalchemy is something that extract only the date from a date/datetime field. SQLserver has not such function unlike other RDBMS. The best match is the sqlserver's convert() function, however it need extra parameters that are not required in original date(). I'm sure that func.DATE() must not be mapped as DATE() in sqlserver dialect. I got also your point, maybe that func.date(when) is a better option than when.date().